# type 'void' has no property 'blob' and no string index signature

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, rxjs

Update1: I updated code on basis of Pankaj answer

hey i updated your code in the codebase...but still I am getting an error like this...any idea...at the end of semicolon [**ts] Property assignment expected.**

```
Observable.fromEvent( $("#AnimalRatsGrid .RatNameFile"), "click")
          .do((e) => {
            console.log("I am here");
            alert("I am here");
            kendo.ui.progress($("#loading"), true);
          }).map(e => "Rats/color/black?RatId="+"7887878787")
          .mergeMap(vals => that.nbcuService.getResponse(vals, 'get', ""))
          //.map(data => { blob: new Blob([data], { type: 'application/octet-stream' }), fire: "untitled1.txt" })
          .map(data => {
              //creating customData object
              let customData: any = {
                  blob: new Blob([data],
                  {
                    type: 'application/octet-stream'
                  }),
                  fire: "untitled1.txt" //
              };
              return customData; //returning it from map.
            })
          .subscribe(
            ({blob, fire}) => that.nbcuService.saveAs(blob,fire),
            err => { }
          );
        });
```

- I am trying to learn rxjs.
- so I included rxjs methods.
- but I am getting three errors in my visual studio.

  **// [ts] Unused label.
  //  [ts] Cannot find name 'fire'.any
  //[ts] Type 'void' has no property 'blob' and no string index signature.**
- can you tell me how to fix..
- providing my relevant code below.
- whole code I am giving in gist https://gist.github.com/texirv0203/e071a9ebea3a6aa0f8a0c65d47f75807

```or-tag-here
Observable.fromEvent($("#AnimalRatsGrid .RatNameFile"), "click")
  .do((e) => {
    console.log("I am here");
    alert("I am here");
    kendo.ui.progress($("#loading"), true);
  }).map(e => "Rats/color/black?RatId=" + "7887878787")
  .mergeMap(vals => that.sportsservice.getResponse(vals, 'get', ""))
  .map(data => {
    blob: new Blob([data], // [ts] Unused label.
      {
        type: 'application/octet-stream'
      }),
    fire: "untitled1.txt" //  [ts] Cannot find name 'fire'.any
  })
  .subscribe(
    //[ts] Type 'void' has no property 'blob' and no string index signature.
    ({
      blob,
      fire
    }) => that.sportsservice.saveAs(blob, fire),
    err => {}
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Typescript is yelling because observable last part, which is `map` function doesn't return any object which is `void`. When you have lambda expression like `.map(item => item.someProp)` that time lambda return RHS implicitly and when you use `{ }` (parentheses) inside lambda function, you have to return desired result from `function` explicitly.

```
.map(data => {
  //creating customData object
  let customData: any = {
      blob: new Blob([data],
      {
         type: 'application/octet-stream'
      }),
      fire: "untitled1.txt" //
   };
   return customData; //returning it from map.
})
```

Comment: hey i updated your code in the codebase...but still I am getting an error like this...any idea...at the end of semicolon [ts] Property assignment expected.---------> update code in the question too